# Do lower and capital letters matter for sha checksum?

Tags: checksum

I have just download a windows iso from microsoft and the checksum does match, unless lower and capital letters must be equal.
Note: i copy pasted the checksum nothing was edited.

```
8f8e54759e54a25d4cbf869a418f57b7c4942a9b2672a8c3fb84396551608b7f
8F8E54759E54A25D4CBF869A418F57B7C4942A9B2672A8C3FB84396551608B7F
```

Comment: yes hash output is case insensitive because its actually a hexadecimal number, rather than text. note however that if you hash text, then case matters, because hashes use bytedata (rather than character data) and, the byte codes for lower case and upper case letters are different.

Answer (score 7):

No, they do not. Simply put, the SHA256 hash is a sequence of 256 bits, which is usually displayed as a sequence of 64 hexadecimal digits instead (each digit being denoted by one of the decimal digits or the first 6 letters in the alphabet, and thus being equivalent to a particular group of 4 bits in the sequence of length 256 when you consider the represented integer in binary form).

It is purely a matter of aesthetics whether a given piece of software chooses to display the hexadecimal digits between 10 and 15 as lower or upper case letters.

Comment: I'd upvote except that you use dimensionless numbers, e.g. *"256-long"*, "long" is not a unit of measurement or quantity.  I was taught that if you're referring to a quantity of something that is measured/counted in a specific unit, then specify that unit with the number.  It's rather rare to be using a pure number (as in your last sentence) versus a quantity of something.  You did try to get the hyphenation correct!